# Python pythonw subprocess check_output not working

Tags: python, sockets, subprocess, background-process, pythonw

I have a problem regarding pythonw. I'm making a program which should be executed in background. When it starts, it's supposed to send the computername, the username and the result of a check to see if the program has admin rights. Here's the relevant piece of the client code:

```
computername = subprocess.check_output("echo %computername%", shell=True).decode(sys.stdout.encoding).splitlines()[0]
username = subprocess.check_output("echo %username%", shell=True).decode(sys.stdout.encoding).splitlines()[0]
isadmin = ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
sleep(0.5)
s.send(computername.encode() + ";;".encode() + username.encode() + ";;".encode() + str(isadmin).encode())
```

And this is the piece of server code that's supposed to receive it:

```
data = conn.recv(1024).decode().split(";;")
print(data)
clientcount += 1
clientlist.append({"conn": conn, "ip": ip, "id": clientcount, "name": data[0] + "\\" + data[1], "isadmin": int(data[2])})
```

(the print line is just for debug)
So here's the problem. When I execute the client code as `client.py`, everything works normally, I get this output:

`['DESKTOP-#######', '######', '0']`

and the code can go on. But when I execute the program as `client.pyw`, as it's supposed to be, I get:

`['']`

So of course I get an IndexError. I'm guessing something goes wrong with the subprocess.check_output. Is it normal? With what could I replace it, so it works in background?

(I'm using python 3.5)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.pyw` doesn't have a console, so there's an issue with `subprocess` when running `pythonw` without redirection of `stdin` (as explained in the duplicate that I just digged out).

In your case, adding `stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` solves the issue, by providing valid streams for input & errors.

But, above all:

```
subprocess.check_output("echo %computername%", shell=True).decode(sys.stdout.encoding).splitlines()[0]
```

is really overkill for

```
os.getenv("computername")
```

that that will work with `pythonw` so do that, it's cleaner, and it will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: Je suppose que tu est français vu ton nom, ça tombe bien, moi aussi ^^. Haha, quel idiot, j'avais complètement oublié os.getenv ==". Je vais utiliser ça, mais sinon, j'ai résolu mon problème. C'était a cause du sys.stdout.encoding, vu que c'est en arrière plan il n'y a pas de stdout ^^". Sans ça ça marche, mais je vais quand même utiliser os.getenv(), plus clean. Merci!

Comment: oui, c'est mieux! yes it's better.